# Titanium Mobile delete files when running

Tags: mobile, titanium

I just started working with titanium mobile and manage to make a first simple application with some tabs.

However as soon as I want to add a window in a separate file (for example in resources/main_windows/main.js) and want to run it, titanium deletes all this files.

Do I have to add this resources in some configuration file, so that titanium doesnt delete this files?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figure it out by myself.

Since I am working with IntelliJ, it added the bin files which are actually automatically generated by titanium at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think you have to put your resource files in the asset folder. Then Titanium will copy them in resorce folder at compile time.